# Cloud Functions times out when calling an external HTTP with a POST request

Tags: python-requests, google-cloud-functions, http-post

I have a Google Cloud Function and within that I called two external APIs (or URLs), using the Python `requests` library, one `requests.get` and another `requests.post`. Please note that these APIs are tested and working using Postman.

The `requests.get` is downloading an MP3 file and it is working in Cloud Functions as I was able to see the downloaded file in Cloud Storage:

```
download_url = "https://some.url.com/music.mp3"
resp = requests.get(download_url)
[get the resp.content, put to storage bucket]
```

Aside from storing in Cloud Storage, I also send this mp3 file over to Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API and get the transcribed text, which I want to post to the another URL.

```
[transcribe the audio using Speech-to-Text API, get the transcibed text]
data = { "download_url": download_url, "transcription": transcribed_text }
upload_api = https://another.url.com/api"
resp = requests.post(upload_api, data = data)
```

Likewise, the transcription is working because I print/log the text and it shows in the View Logs console of Cloud Functions. In the `requests.post` however, I am getting a time out, also according to the logs.

```
requests.post(upload_api, data = data, timeout=120)
```

[image]

[image]

I even lengthen the timeout setting but that still happens. What could be the explanation for this? Is there a Google Cloud configuration that I miss to set somewhere that might be causing this?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Can you display the log trace with the timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because GCP cloud functions has a 1 minute timeout, to fix it is necessary to declare the timeout limit when you create your function

if you are using Gcloud CLI commands to deploy your function, you need to add the flag --timeout

for example

```
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --timeout=TIMEOUT FLAGS
```

if you are using the GCP console (Web UI) you need to follow the steps on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout)